# Determining the physical address from a virtual memory's page table

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, pagination, virtual-memory

Assuming a virtual memory paging system with pages 4k long, I was given the following table

```
      P A M
0x003 1 1 0
0x04A 0 0 0
0xA78 1 1 1
0x0A1 1 0 0
0x000 1 0 0

*(P = presence digit, A = access digit, ; M = modified digit)*
```

and asked what is the real address of `0x003A78`.

I am a bit lost here, I guess the idea is to decompose `0x003A78` in 2? That'd be 0x003 A78, so it'd be `(2 * 4k) + 0x078` ?

Is this it or am I completing off on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first colomn would be "number of physical page". You just have to use the number of virtual page (`0x3A78 / 0x1000`, that is 3) as index to that table.

The page is present, so the physical page number is correct, that means that the physical address would be `0xA1 * 0x1000 + 0xA78`, or `0x0A1A78`.